# How to render Nepali text in a matploitlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

How can i display the words ("आन्तरिक") in both x and ylabels. Currently they are not recognized by matploitlib?[enter image description here][1]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

font_path = '/home/dip/WebScraping/fonts/PREETI.TTF'

font = FontProperties(fname=font_path)

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [10,9,8,7,6]
plt.xlabel("आन्तरिक")

plt.ylabel("आन्तरिक")

plt.plot(x,y)

plt.show()
```

[Image of abouve Output][1]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't installed and checked the actual font, but I think the following code will help.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
fp = FontProperties(fname=r'/home/dip/WebScraping/fonts/PREETI.TTF', size=16)

plt.xlabel("Nepali", fontproperties=fp)
plt.ylabel("Nepali", fontproperties=fp)
plt.legend(loc="upper left", prop=fp)
```

Comment: I'm glad you've solved the problem. Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

font_path = '/home/dip/WebScraping/fonts/Mangal.ttf'

font = FontProperties(fname=font_path)

x = [1,2,3,4,5]

y = [10,9,8,7,6]

plt.xlabel("आन्तरिक", fontproperties=font)

plt.ylabel("आन्तरिक", fontproperties=font)

plt.plot(x,y)

plt.show()
```